# C++ - How can I have a function return an object before it's class is declared?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, types

How can I construct an object before it's class appears in the source file?

For instance I have a class "Poo":

```
Class Poo{
  Person Girate(int Magnitude){
    //Code Stuff
    return person;
  }
};
```

As you can see the member function "Girate" must return an instance of "Person", which doesn't appear until later:

```
Class Person{
  Poo Hydrate(int Direction){
    //more Code Stuff
    return poo;
  }
};
```

Comment: Dude - that's what [forward declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) were INVENTED for!  How can you have the unmitigated chutzpah to REJECT *the* solution to the very problem you're asking about???  That's like saying "I'm reakkt thirsty, but I don't ask me to drink anything"!!!!

Comment: "I need" why do you think so?

Comment: this is a Crap question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
class A;                 // A forward declaration. A is an incomplete type at this point

class B
{
    A a();               // Okay to declare a function with incomplete return type
                         // but it would be an error to try defining it here
};

class A 
{
    B b();
};                       // A is a complete type now

A B::a() { return A(); } // Can define B::a() now since the return type is complete
B A::b() { return B(); }
```

Edit: there is no way to do this without forward declarations.

Comment: I thought the OP (for whatever reason) said he didn't want to use a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)?  But you're correct - this is "The Solution".